# LAPACK environment missing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, lapack

Recently I was using  scikit learn to process text documents. While doing that i got some numpy warnings when I googled the problem they asked me to reinstall scipy and numpy.

So what I did is completely remove scipy and numpy and tried to re install them.

But the problem that I got is my synaptic says fix broken dependencies first.

So I switched to 'pip' to install the whole thing.

When I tried pip, it said BLAS & LAPACK missing, installed BLAS with f77(g77) compiler.

But when installing LAPACK it is not installing with f77 and the internet asked me to install gfortran. But I have not been successful in that attempt.

Is there any alternative for this ? I just need to install scipy back.

Answer (score 1):

Installing numpy and scipy can really be a pain. I usually use [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads) to avoid having to mess with those 2 packages. Enthought Python Distribution is another solid choice. These things tend to "just work" without fussing with fortran, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I almost wasted half of my day. Anaconda finished it in 10 mins :|